# How ldd executable finds /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, linker

When I run

```
ldd ./myprogram
```

it shows:

```
...
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/stdc++.so.6
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6
...
```

/usr/lib64 is not in my LD_LIBRARY_PATH, how does it finds /usr/lib64?  When I link 'myprgrom', it was linking libraries from ${HOME}/mynewgcc/.../lib64.

Comment: Look in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`

Comment: @Brian: thanks for reply.  I've checked that:
cat ld.so.conf shows "include ld.so.conf.d/*.conf".  'cat' *.conf 
under that dir shows:

    /usr/lib64/atlas
    hwcap 1 nosegneg
    hwcap 1 nosegneg
    /usr/local/lib
    /usr/lib64/mysql
    /usr/lib64/R/lib
    /usr/lib64/xulrunner

don't see /usr/lib64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ldconfig` program builds a cache for `ld.so` (called by `ldd`) or `ld-linux.so`.  Shared objects in  `/etc/ld.so.conf` and `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` get added to this cache.  These paths are cached to allow for faster lookup (as opposed to looking at arbitrary places in the filesystem like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`).  There are certain defaults for `ldconfig` as well, namely `/lib`, `/lib64`, `/usr/lib`, and `/usr/lib64` (the "trusted" directories) which get added to the directories in the config files (unless `ldconfig -n` is specified).

Comment: please see my comment above to Brian.  I don't see /usr/lib64 in these conf files.  Anything I am missing

Comment: I just added a clarification about the trusted directories.